# Product count in Magento layered category navigation

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento and I can't work out how to display the number of products in a category in the category list efficiently. I've done it by hacking _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml on the instance of Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation but it's a stupid hacky solution.

All I want is something like:

- Product (1)
- Product (4)
- Product (50)

I've read stuff about /app/design/frontend/default/theme_name/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml but after adding it to my theme no edits seem to make any effect. I have also tried editing the default and blank versions and no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can echo the product count by using this:

```
echo $_category->getProductCount()
```

You can add this code to your template (depending on which template you have, mine is rightnav.phtml) in app/frontend/default/YOUR TEMPLATE/catalog/navigation/TEMPLATE NAME.PHTML

example:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this-  >isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> <?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>
```

Comment: Where abouts would you put that though? In which .phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

**getProductCount** method gets all products number that assigned to that category(not checks **is_active** or **is_in_stock** etc.)